# Learning Twitter Bootstrap recommendations

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would really like to learn how to use Twitter Bootstrap 3. The problem is that it seems I can't find a good source to learn it from. Any source I've tried so far assumed that you somehow have some knowledge and wasn't explaining what are the available classes for elements, what are the classes they have used are actually doing etc.

I simply want a source it can either be a book/videos or w/e that will start from scratch and if possible, will use `HTML5`, `modernizr` and `respond.js` to make it cross-browser supported and actually give me a start point (base folder just like H5BP) which I can then later on start building my own websites.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bootstrap is CSS, html, and jQuery. If you don't know that, then learn basics first.

    http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/29/useful-glossaries-for-web-designers-and-developers/
    http://www.cssbasics.com/
    http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/
    http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design
    http://www.splio.com/responsive/
    http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/
    http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @BootstrapThemer I'm not new to css/html. I've been developing websites for years. Up until now I was doing everything manually and finally thought that using bootstrap would save me a tremendous amount of time so I've decided to learn it. Thanks for your advice tho.

Comment: @kfirba look for tutorials about the bootstrap grid system everything will flow naturally after that.  The basic attributes themselves you can easily learn from the bootstrap documentation.  Also read up on `LESS` since that is what bootstrap is created with.

Comment: Take a look at [Bootply](http://bootply.com). There are several different starter examples you can play with, and [read this article](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) for a great explanation of how the grid works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bootstrap docs are really helpful, probably the best resource.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
http://getbootstrap.com/components

Comment: still not enough. I want something that starts from scratch and slowly teaches you everything there is to know. Just like any PHP guide you will find or some PHP frameworks

Comment: @kfirba This looks useful: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/

Comment: I will take a look at this :) thanks! Edit: I've taken a look at this in depth and it seems to be exactly what i'm looking for. It's explaining each property that bootstrap has to offer. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 8):

My first recommendation is to learn CSS in depth.  Oftentimes, Bootstrap is just not necessary, but developers rely on it because they are too lazy to master CSS fundamentals.  You are welcome to check my book series - Functional CSS - which covers almost the entirety of CSS using practical examples.

If you are keen on sticking with Bootstrap, then you can 1) print the source code for their example ([Bootstrap examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples)) and simply re-implement them on your own, typing each block of code one line at a time and observing the effect, and 2) read the Bootstrap source code.  The latter is a bit over 6000 lines and should not take long to go through.  And, 3) reflecting on what you have learned in 1 and 2, create personal realistic website that uses Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a good source here is one: http://ieatcss.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial.html

3 Step by step real time examples are used in Ieatcss bootstrap 3 tutorial. You can easily understand them without any knowledge of the basics.

Don't worry about learning CSS & other messy things. The tutorials in http://ieatcss.com is targeted at complete beginners, you can easily understand them.

Regards,
Hussain.